# Add attachement to message : Discord Webhook [BATCH]

Tags: batch-file, curl, discord, webhooks

I've searched all around internet, trying to combien only file command with only content command, but, nothing work, i would like to get some help, i need a curl command to but in .bat / batch file that send a message to a discord webhook like New message and the file message.txt has attachment to the message, all of that in the same message, not in two separed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference, if you want to include an attachment with a webhook message, you need to use `multipart/form-data`. In `curl`, this is done with the `-F` flag.

Like usual, the `{"content":"message"}` json format still applies for sending text, and because Windows is weird about single quotes, everything needs double quotes but the inner quotes need to be escaped with `\`.

```
set "message_text=This is a test message with an attachment."
set "attachment=message.txt"
curl -k -F "payload_json={\"content\": \"%message_text%\"}" -F "file1=@%attachment%" %WEBHOOK%
```

I'm assuming that you've set the `%WEBHOOK%` variable to the full URL of your actual webhook